# Built in Function for Sort Alpha Numeric Values

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, arraylist, linked-list

I just need to know if there is any built-in functionality to implement Sort functionality[Alpha-Numeric] in Dot Net. If there please Let me know.

Here is what i need

**Input :** 
data0
data1
data10
data19
data2
data22
data3
data31

**Ouput :**

data0
data1
data2
data3
data10
data19
data22
data31

Comment: there isnt anything built in to treat "data9" as less than "data100" because characters/strings are not numbers.  you could write your own sorter or possibly assign a value to these things depending on what they are

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in function for what you are looking for. If "data" is always the same length like in the example. You can compare the length of the string then the string itself.

```
Private Function Comparer(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Integer

    If x.Length = y.Length Then
        Return String.Compare(x, y)
    End If

    Return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length)
End Function

Sub Main()

    Dim v As New List(Of String)

    v.Add("data0")
    v.Add("data1")
    v.Add("data10")
    v.Add("data19")
    v.Add("data2")
    v.Add("data22")
    v.Add("data3")
    v.Add("data31")

    v.Sort(AddressOf Comparer)

    For Each s As String In v
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```